# Is there a way to crack a 129 character length hash?

Tags: hash

I was given a 129 character length hash ( probably whirlwind or SHA-512) to decrypt. I have tried cracking it using the whirlpooldeep and hashcat tools (without wordlists, i.e dictionary attack) but with no success. I'm sorry for the ambiguous question but this is all the information I have about my current task. Any suggestion would be gladly appreciated

Comment: I think you have missed the point of a HASH. Hash functions are typically not invertible, meaning that it is not possible to reconstruct the input from its hash alone. I am confused therefore why you are trying to 'crack' a hash.

Comment: I was thinking the same, I have read about hash functions and why there is impossible to invert them, but the task simply says: crack it.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to guess the original data. Maybe it's told in the question in some hidden way, which you will uncover only if you read the question several times and pay attention to the detail.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer was just to find a website who had an extremely large database of decoded hashes. The only site capable of decoding my hash was down since 3 days ago but now is fully operational. I have spent 2 whole days downloading and installing various software and trying different websites but with no succes up until now.

Comment: The guys who made up this task did not take into consideration the downtime of the website; at least I now know more about hashes in general because of the time spent reading about them and your answers. Thank you for your interest and time

Comment: Misuse of words: instead of decoding a hash, have an extremely large database of words and/or computer power to match hashes of existing words to mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this task is feasible because whoever gave you the hash has prepared it on purpose in a way so you have a chance to crack it. If this is not the case, you have no chance at current computer performance and will not within the next few decades.

So, assuming it is feasible, e.g. because the hash is of some short data like less than 10 bytes:

You are probably making a mistake in how you compare the hashes. The hash should not be of length 129. It should be of length 128. That you see a file with 129 bytes is probably because there is a line feed (\n) at the end of the file.

Moreover, you should, for performance, not compare the hashes in hexadecimal format (length 128), but instead in binary format (length 64).

Comment: Indeed there has to be something special about it, it's just that I have no remaining ideas about how to do it, thank you for the length correction.

Answer (score 1):

A [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) seems to be the perfect tool for your scenario.

There is a software called [RainbowCrack](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2006/02/password-cracking-with-rainbowcrack-and-rainbow-tables/) to do this sort of reversing a hash. There should be rainbow tables available for SHA-512, which should be, roughly estimated, about 1TB in size (for finding original data of length up to 9 bytes).

Using this kind of hash reversal is likely to take you a day or two to get into the matter and understand it, and if it's feasible, after downloading the 1TB, you are likely to get the result in less than a day.

Before you start all this, I would ask the source of your hash how long the data is that you are searching for. This could easily end up being a kid's joke, e.g. that your source hashed 512bit of random data, in which case you would have absolutely no chance and you would waste your time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I'll try looking into this matter